# Flipper-DoubleConversion Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

While compiling a react native project in Xcode, I get the error "Flipper-DoubleConversion error build: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code". I am using react-native version 0.68.2.
[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZELtv.png)
How can I solve this error?